# How to wait until user selects a popup blocker

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have three jsp pages

1.index.jsp
2.show.jsp

from index.jsp i want to send request to show.jsp(it will opens jnlp file) and execute the remaining code in index.jsp and it will redirect to another page

for this i have done the following code

```
   <%
    Config.loadConfigFile();
    String openValue = Config.getValue("open");
    String jnlpURL = "";
      if(openValue != null && !openValue.equals(""))
        jnlpURL = "index.jsp";
    %>
    <a id="linkToClick" href='<%=jnlpURL%>' target="_blank" hidden = "true" /a>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    var test = '<%=openValue%>'
    if(test != null && test != "")
      document.getElementById('linkToClick').click();
  window.open('admCmdError.jsp',--------);      
    </script>
```

it is working fine(ie; opening jnlp file and redirecting to another page) only in case of brower disabled popup's

but, the problem is if popup's are enabled on browers then it is showing the popup blocker and immediately(very fast) redirecting to another page ie; it is not waiting until user select the popup blocker and allow

i tried to sleep some time but it is not working

Advance Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if(test != null && test != "")
  {
   var popUp = window.open('admCmdError.jsp', 'testpopup', 'width=1000, height=700, left=24, top=24, scrollbars, resizable');
   if (popUp == null || typeof(popUp)=='undefined') {   
alert('Please disable your pop-up blocker'); 
  } 
  else {    
document.getElementById('linkToClick').click();
  }
 }
```